# SQL-Server Query Calculating Ocupation Rate Per Month

Tags: sql, sql-server, outsystems

I'm working on a booking application and i'm creating a query that calculates the occupation rate of an Hotel by month. To do that i must check the checkin and checkout dates of all bookings and increment some variables and associate them to the corresponding months. 
I only need to measure this rates on the current year.
If a booking has a checkout date or checkin date in wich the month is March (for example) i need to increment the variable that corresponds to the ocupation in that month. And i need to do this for every booking in that year interval.

Booking has a checkin date and a checkout date, the other attributes are not relevant for this query, the input parameters are BeginDate (2015-01-01 ) and EndDate (2015-12-31).

```
Month       Ocupation
[JANUARY] | 29
[FEBRUARY] | 20
[MARCH] | 30
....... | ...
```

This is what i did so far, i'm kinda lost at this moment. Any help would be appreciated.

```
   Select  
        SUM(CASE WHEN datename(month, [CheckIn]) = 'January' or datename(month, [CheckOut]) = 'January' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)  January,
        SUM(CASE WHEN datename(month, [CheckIn]) = 'February' or datename(month, [CheckOut]) = 'February' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) February,
        SUM(CASE WHEN datename(month, [CheckIn]) = 'March' or datename(month, [CheckOut]) = 'March' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) March,
        SUM(CASE WHEN datename(month, [CheckIn]) = 'April' or datename(month, [CheckOut]) = 'April' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)  April,
        SUM(CASE WHEN datename(month, [CheckIn]) = 'May' or datename(month, [CheckOut]) = 'May' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)  May,
        SUM(CASE WHEN datename(month, [CheckIn]) = 'June' or datename(month, [CheckOut]) = 'June' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) June,
        SUM(CASE WHEN datename(month, [CheckIn]) = 'July' or datename(month, [CheckOut]) = 'July' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) July,
        SUM(CASE WHEN datename(month, [CheckIn]) = 'August' or datename(month, [CheckOut]) = 'August' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) August,
        SUM(CASE WHEN datename(month, [CheckIn]) = 'September' or datename(month, [CheckOut]) = 'September' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) September,
        SUM(CASE WHEN datename(month, [CheckIn]) = 'October' or datename(month, [CheckOut]) = 'October' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) October,
        SUM(CASE WHEN datename(month, [CheckIn]) = 'November' or datename(month, [CheckOut]) = 'November' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) November,
        SUM(CASE WHEN datename(month, [CheckIn]) = 'December' or datename(month, [CheckOut]) = 'December' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) December
FROM {Booking} INNER JOIN {Status} ON {Booking}.[StatusId] = {Status}.[Id]
WHERE {Booking}.[CheckIn] >= @BeginDate AND {Booking}.[CheckOut]  <= @EndDate AND {Status}.[Label] <> 'Canceled'
```

Comment: can you post up some sample data?

Comment: And desired results?  There is not enough information to answer your question.

Comment: If a booking has a CheckIn in say January and a CheckOut in February, should it count as 1 for both Jan and Feb?

Comment: yes, it should count for both months @jpw

Comment: What problem are you experiencing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that you want to count bookings where CheckIn and CheckOut occurs in the same month as 1 occupation for that month, and bookings that have CheckIn and CheckOut in different months as 1 for each month then this query should work:

```
SELECT 
    Month, 
    'Occupation' = COUNT(MonthNo)
FROM Booking 
OUTER APPLY (
    SELECT MonthNo, Month FROM (
       VALUES (1, 'January'), (2, 'February'), (3, 'March'),(4, 'April'), (5, 'May')
    ) AS Months (MonthNo, Month) 
    WHERE MonthNo BETWEEN MONTH(CheckIn) AND MONTH(CheckOut)
) c
-- WHERE CheckIn >= @BeginDate 
--   AND CheckOut  <= @EndDate 
--   AND [Status].[Label] <> 'Canceled' 
GROUP BY Month, MonthNo ORDER BY MonthNo
```

I used a table value constructor to make the table with month numbers and names inline, but if you already have a suitable calendar table (which you should) then use that instead.

Given a input table like:

```
Id  CheckIn     CheckOut
1   2015-01-30  2015-03-31 -- 1 for Jan, Feb, Mar
2   2015-01-03  2015-01-05 -- 1 for Jan
3   2015-01-30  2015-02-05 -- 1 for Jan, Feb
4   2015-01-30  2015-01-31 -- 1 for Jan
5   2015-02-01  2015-02-03 -- 1 for Feb
6   2015-03-22  2015-04-01 -- 1 for Mar, Apr
7   2015-03-23  2015-04-03 -- 1 for Mar, Apr
8   2015-03-30  2015-03-31 -- 1 for Mar
9   2015-04-01  2015-04-03 -- 1 for Apr
10  2015-04-28  2015-05-01 -- 1 for Apr, May
11  2015-05-01  2015-05-03 -- 1 for May
```

it would produce an output like:

```
Month   Occupation
January     4
February    3
March       4
April       4
May         2
```